# Calculate how many ways to get change of 78

Tags: combinatorics

I been asked to calculate how many ways there are to get change of 78 cents with the coins of 25,10,5,1.

I been able to write this down:

$25a + 10b + 5c + d = 78$

But I do not know how to continue. Can you help me please?

Comment: For whoever is not too lazy to write down a full solution and wants to check their answer, Mathematica gives me $121$.

Comment: @ronno. Could you show me how you wrote this problem using Mathematica ? Thanks.

Comment: @ronno I am more interest in understanding how the calculation is done, rather than solving it.

Comment: What's wrong with the various programs that people supplied you in answer to [your earlier question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15872/194)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I want to understand the math behind it.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as the coefficient of $x^{78}$ in $$(x^3+x^8+x^{13}+\cdots+x^{78})(1+x^5+x^{10}+\cdots+x^{75})(1+x^{10}+x^{20}+\cdots+x^{70})(1+x^{25}+x^{50}+x^{75})$$ That doesn't help you much by hand, but it gives you something concrete to enter into a CAS if that helps.

Comment: And if you replace the finite geometric series by the corresponding infinite ones, you get a shorter expression to write down.

Comment: Is the last term in the third parenthesis supposed to be $x^{60}$ or is it $x^{70}$?

Comment: @E.O. Good eyes ! Yes

Answer (score -1):

Consider the product in alex.jordan's answer. The product of the last two factors is
$$1 + x^{10} + x^{20} + x^{25} + x^{30} + x^{35} + x^{40} + x^{45} + 2 x^{50} + x^{55}
+ 2 x^{60} +  x^{65} + 2 x^{70} + 2 x^{75} + \ldots)$$
The product of the first two is
$$ 1 + \ldots + x^4 + 2 (x^5 + \ldots + x^9) + 3 (x^{10}+\ldots+x^{14}) + \ldots
+ 16 (x^{75}+\ldots+x^{79})+\ldots$$
So the coefficient of $x^{78}$ is 
$$ \eqalign{ 16 & \text{ for } 1 \times 16 x^{78}\cr
+ 14 & \text{ for } x^{10} \times 14 x^{68}\cr
+ 12 & \text{ for } x^{20} \times 12 x^{58}\cr
+ \ldots\cr
+ 2 & \text{ for } 2x^{75} \times x^3}$$

Comment: I don't understand how the coefficient is helping me

Comment: Note that my answer has been changed. Since you have to have 3 pennies mod 5, the first factor can be changed to something simpler.

Comment: @Babibu One way to get 78 cents is three pennies and three quarters. This is represented by a term $x^3\cdot1\cdot1\cdot x^{75}$ when that expression is multiplied out. Another way is eight pennies, five nickels, two dimes, and one quarter, represented by $x^8\cdot x^{25}\cdot x^{20}\cdot x^{25}$. Etc. These representations all simplify to $x^{78}$, and algebraically the final coefficient of $x^{78}$ is just counting up how many such representations there were.

Comment: It seems to me that calculating the coefficient of $x^{78}$ is just as hard a problem (if not harder) for a *human* to do ...

Answer (score -1):

There may be a faster, more clever method, but I would do this by nested casework, on the number of coins of each size.

---

**Case 1: No quarters**

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 1.1: No dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ Our final set of coins is fully determined by how many nickels we have. There are $16$ $\hspace{1cm}$ $\hspace{1cm}$ choices for the number of nickels $\left(0, 5, 10, \dots 75\right)$.

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 1.2: One dime**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ Similarly, we have $14$ choices for the number of nickels.

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 1.3: Two dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $12$ in this case. You should notice the pattern, and hopefully the reason for it.

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 1.4: Three dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $10$

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 1.5: Four dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $8$

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 1.6: Five dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $6$

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 1.7: Six dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $4$

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 1.8: Seven dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $2$

**Case 2: One quarter**

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 2.1: No dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ Here we have $11$ choices for the number of nickels used. The corresponding cent values $\hspace{2.1cm}$ are $0$, $5$, $\dots 50$

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 2.2: One dime**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ We have a pattern again. $9$ in this case.

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 2.3: Two dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $7$

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 2.4: Three dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $5$

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 2.5: Four dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $3$

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 2.6: Five dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ $1$ choice - no nickels

**Case 3: Two quarters**

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 2.1: No dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ We have $28$ cents left to spend. There are $6$ possibilities for the number of nickels ($0$ to  $\hspace{1cm}$ $\hspace{1.1cm}$ $5$ nickels).

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 2.2: One dime**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ 4

$\hspace{1cm}$ **Case 2.3: Two dimes**

$\hspace{1cm}$$\hspace{1cm}$ 2

**Case 4: Three quarters**

$\hspace{1cm}$ There is only one way to complete this: three pennies.

---

Our final answer is the sum of the number of possibilities in each case. This is $$16 + 14 + 12 + 10 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2 + 11 + 9 + 7 + 5 + 3 + 1 + 6 + 4 + 2 + 1 = \boxed{121}$$