# how many combination of coins add up to \$20?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

we have five coins:

- Coin 1: \$1.
- Coin 2: \$2.
- Coin 3: \$5.
- Coin 4: \$10.
- Coin 5: \$20.

  In how many way can we get \$20 using those coins and combinations of them?

The only way I could do that was by counting all possibilities and it took forever.I started counting with this in mind : "in how many ways can only one of coins add up to \$20" . then went for combination of 2 coins ,after that of 3 coins . I got total of 40 combinations but it was very time consuming and illogical because if you have like \$50 to add up to you will never count that by hand .

Is there any other easier way maybe ,formula ?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this, but indeed this exact problem has been haunting me for a good 15 years ... I think generating functions will provide an answer!

Comment: I don't think there is an easy formula, but I would personally prefer to split into cases not depending on how many coins you use, but depending on how many $\$20$ coins you use. And in each of those cases split again depending on how many $\$10$ coins you use, and so on. To me, it seems a little easier not to miss possibilities that way.

Comment: I thought of rewriting it in algebraic form like this
$x$+$2y$+$5z$+$10a$+$20b$=20 (where $x,y,z,a,b$ are non-negative integers). 
but is it helpful? for me it gave nothing...
I mean it's same, only way I could do that was again by counting possibilities.

Comment: Similar questions discussed in many places, e.g., https://www.maa.org/frank-morgans-math-chat-293-ways-to-make-change-for-a-dollar and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203864/how-many-ways-you-can-make-change-for-an-amount and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027067/how-many-ways-can-you-make-change-for-a-dollar and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607533/calculate-how-many-ways-to-get-change-of-78 and many, many more.

Comment: Thanks i'll read them all.

Comment: Coin analysis is standard in Groebner basis; although it is usually demonstrated for minimizing.  I am reasonably sure it can be extended to count via. the basis result.
Search google for something like 
"Bernd Sturmfels groebner video coins berkeley"
There was a great elementary presentation on the MSRI website but I can't locate that particular one.  There are other instructional videos there though.

Comment: For instance:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNO5WuxuNak
12 minutes in (or so).

Comment: I'll watch that video . I really want to understand this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $41$ combinations in all.  The following solution is essentially a twist on the usual approach using generating functions.

Start by noticing that if we want to make a total of 20 dollars, we can use any combination of the 2, 5, 10, and 20 dollar coins and make up the rest with 1 dollar coins.  So we can solve the problem without 1 dollar coins for $r$ dollars for $0 \le r \le 20$ and add up the 21 solutions to get the total number of combinations.  Let's say $a_r$ is the number of solutions (not using 1 dollar coins) for $r$ dollars.  If you think about it a bit, I think you can see that $a_r$ is the coefficient of $x^r$ in a polynomial which we will denote by $f(x)$, defined by
$$f(x) = P_2(x) P_5(x) P_{10}(x) P_{20}(x)$$
where
$$\begin{align}
P_2(x) &= 1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + \dots + x^{20} \\
P_5(x) &= 1 + x^5 + x^{10} + x^{15} + x^{20} \\
P_{10}(x) &= 1 + x^{10} + x^{20} \\
P_{20}(x) &= 1 + x^{20} \\
\end{align}$$
To see this, think about the way multiplication of polynomials works.  It may help to start by computing a smaller example, say $P_{10}(x) P_{20}(x)$, and see how the result relates to the problem of making change with only 10 and 20 dollar coins.

Expanding $f(x)$ is a straightforward computation.  We start by computing $P_{20}(x)P_{10}(x)$, then compute $P_{20}(x)P_{10}(x)P_5(x)$, and then finish with $P_{20}(x)P_{10}(x)P_5(x)P_2(x)$. And since we are only interested in $a_r$ for $r \le 20$, we can discard any powers of $x$ higher than $x^{20}$. So here goes:

$$P_{20}(x) P_{10}(x) = 1+x^{10}+2 x^{20}+ O(x^{30})$$
$$P_{20}(x) P_{10}(x) P_5(x) = 1+x^5+2 x^{10}+2 x^{15}+4 x^{20} + O(x^{25})$$
$$P_{20}(x) P_{10}(x) P_5(x) P_2(x) = 1+x^2+x^4+x^5 + \\ x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+3 x^{10}  + \\ x^{11}+3 x^{12}+x^{13}+3 x^{14}+3 x^{15}  + \\3
   x^{16}+3 x^{17}+3 x^{18}+3 x^{19}+7 x^{20}+O(x^{21})$$

This last polynomial is $f(x)$, and if we sum its coefficients up to the coefficient of $x^{20}$ we find the answer to the problem is $41$.

Comment: Thank you , it's very good answer ,too bad that my math level isn't that high and i can't understand everything out of it .Anyways thank you i accepted your answer

Comment: The one thing I can't understand is why you discard possibilities with \$1. You said "So we can solve the problem without 1 dollar coins for r dollars for 0≤r≤20 and add up the 21 solutions to get the total number of combinations." but where did you add those 21 ?

Comment: @alexnat009 The sum is $1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+3+1+3+1+3+3+3+3+3+3+7 = 41$ unless I have made a mistake copying those numbers.

Comment: I understood how you got 41 there  , only thing I can't is where did possibilities involving 1 go ? I mean you said  "So we can solve the problem without 1 dollar coins and then add all possibilities with 1 " where are those possibilities. 
to explain what i mean look at this $f(x)=P_{2}(x)P_{5}(x)P_{10}(x)P_{20}(x)$ this is all possibilities with combination of $2$,$5$,$10$ and $20$ but where are possibilities with $1$

Comment: @alexnat009 If you have a combination using only 2,5,10, and 20 that adds up to less than 20, you can add in 1 dollar coins (in only one way) to make the total 20.

Comment: yooo it makes much  sense now . thank you very much because of your answer i want to study discrete math . very good answering btw.